# Grafana - Loki data source receiving 400 Unauthorized error

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-eks, grafana-loki

EKS 1.23, Prometheus-stack with Grafana v7.3.5

Installed Loki v2.7.3 and now trying to connect Grafana to Loki.

I added Loki datasource from Grafana and configured the `loki-gateway` service url:

[image]

Then I get the following error:

`Loki: Bad Request. 400. Authentication to data source failed`

From loki-gateway pod's logs:

```
10.7.60.60 - - [01/Mar/2023:14:18:53 +0000]  401 "GET /loki/api/v1/label?start=1677679732842000000 HTTP/1.1" 10 "-" "Grafana/7.3.5" "10.7.127.117, 10.0.60.21, 10.0.60.21"
```

NOTE: loki-gateway `basicAuth` is disabled by default, hence no need to add user & password to Loki data source in Grafana.

Tried:

1. Enable loki-gateway `basicAuth` and pass the credentials through Grafana Loki Data Source.
2. Skip tls verification

Both ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using loki helm chart to deploy, check if `auth_enabled` value is set to true (it's true by default), set it false and upgrade.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same promblem, then i check grafana log

```
kubectl logs -n grafana-loki-dev loki-grafana-66dcf659b4-8qk22 grafana -f
```

it shows

[image]

You can specify the orgid by adding an HTTP Header 'X-Scope-OrgID' in the Data Source configuration on the Grafana panel. Here, you can set the value of the Header to the orgid you want. This way, when Grafana proxies access to Loki's API, it will have the correct Header and thus successfully authenticate and obtain access.

Comment: X-Scope-OrgID is tenant configurated in promtail